# Swift: How to trigger a function call in viewcontroller from Singleton Class

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, singleton

I have simplified the code a lot but basically i am listening for changes in a collection in firestore in my singleton class 'GetUserData'. Whenever there is a change (a document is added, deleted or modified) in the collection, i need respondToUserGroupsChanges() function in my viewcontroller to be called. The print statement "Collection changed" shows whenever there is a change in the collection so the listener is working properly. But the respondToUserGroupsChanges() function in ViewController is never called. What am i doing wrong? I can try using some flag (for when there is a change) and didSet but i want to figure out why this approach is not working since i believe i have done this before.

```
class GetUserData{
    static let shared = GetUserData()
    var respondToUserGroupsChanges : (() -> Void)?

    
    func observeUserGroupsChanges(){
            db.collection("users").document(currentUserID!).collection("groups").addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
            guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
                print("Error fetching snapshots: \(error!)")
                return
            }
            
            print("Collection changed")
            self.respondToUserGroupsChanges?()
    }
}


class ViewController: UIViewController{
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
       
     
        GetUserData.shared.observeUserGroupsChanges()
      
        GetUserData.shared.respondToUserGroupsChanges = self.respondToUserGroupsChanges
        
        
       
    }


    func respondToUserGroupsChanges(){
    
        print("respond")
    }
    
}
```

Comment: So in your `observeUserGroupsChanges` method, log the value of respondToUserGroupsChanges. I'm guessing it's nil.

Answer (score 0):

In your simplified code, you first invoke `observeUserGroupsChanges()` (`respondToUserGroupsChanges` will be nil) and **then** you set `GetUserData.shared.respondToUserGroupsChanges` to a non-nil value.

Edit your function so you can see what's going on:

```
    func observeUserGroupsChanges(){
        print("Collection changed")
        let notNil = self.respondToUserGroupsChanges == nil ? "" : "not "
        print("self.respondToUserGroupsChanges is \(notNil)nil")
        self.respondToUserGroupsChanges?()
    }
```

Then reverse the order of those 2 steps:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        //First set GetUserData.shared.respondToUserGroupsChanges to a non-nil value
        GetUserData.shared.respondToUserGroupsChanges = self.respondToUserGroupsChanges

        //Now when you call observeUserGroupsChanges, `respondToUserGroupsChanges` won't be nil.
        GetUserData.shared.observeUserGroupsChanges()
    }
```

Comment: Hey that was a typo i made when i simplified the code. i edited my function and added your code and it is not nil. Is there any other thing you can think of?

Comment: When I run your code with the setup order changed, it works as expected and the `respondToUserGroupsChanges` closure gets called. It's hard to help you debug different code with different behavior without seeing that code.